# Is there an easy way to import the configuration of a WSO2 ESB into WSO2 Developer Studio?

Tags: wso2-integration-studio

I am trying to connect my WSO2 Developer Studio (on top of eclipse kepler) with an existing WSO2 Carbon ESB server. Is there an easy way to import the existing services, registry, ... automaticly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option to import the existing services automatically.

You can import the artifacts in the server to an ESB Config project by navigating to the relevant location of the server. ($ESB_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/..)